# Can traffic spy see username and password of MQTT client

Tags: mqtt, security, tls

Can Traffic spy see the username and password of client send to broker when broker don't use TLS ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, without TLS the CONNECT packet is sent in the clear so all of it's content can be seen.

A full breakdown of how to decode the CONNECT packet can be found [here](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718028)